# ios TabBar standard Symbol

Tags: ios, tabbar

I thought that there are standard symbols for the TabBar - but I'm having a hard time finding them! So - are there any at all? If so - where can I find them? I'm using Xcode 4.3, I develop for ios 4 and 5

I'm looking for symbols for the keywords: information, warning/alert, configuration, settings, email

Or do I need to get them from a third party source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are. When creating the `UITabBarItem`, initialise it with [`initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/initWithTabBarSystemItem%3atag%3a) and for the first argument use the [`UITabBarSystemItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITabBarSystemItem)  constant for the image you want ([see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITabBarSystemItem) for a list of all the possible values and corresponding images available). This feature has been around since iOS 2.0 so you'll have no problems with compatibility.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought there might be more system items (like symbols for information, email, ...). I found a website providing icons! http://thenounproject.com